# Getting the results simultaneously from different sources

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

python newbie here!

I am trying to write a small program for myself which is basically getting price information from different exchanges and comparing them, so far it is working great but honestly, I want to make it better in terms of performance and efficiency.

What I mean by efficiency is my program is checking prices step by step and printing the results. My question is can I convert it to checking the prices simultaneously from different exchanges and print them all at the same time?

Below is the part of the code that I wrote:

```
        #Novadax
        symbol_novadax = coin_list[i] + "_USDT"
        response_novadax = requests.get('https://api.novadax.com/v1/market/ticker?symbol=' + symbol_novadax)
        novadax_dic = json.loads(response_novadax.content)
        try:
            if "ask" in novadax_dic["data"]:
                novadax_bid_price = float(novadax_dic["data"]["bid"])
                print("novadax_bid_price "+str(novadax_bid_price))
                novadax_ask_price = float(novadax_dic["data"]['ask'])
                print("novadax_ask_price " + str(novadax_ask_price))
                if (max_bid_val < novadax_bid_price):
                    max_bid_val = novadax_bid_price
                    max_bid_place = "novadax"
                if (min_ask_val > novadax_ask_price):
                    min_ask_val = novadax_ask_price
                    min_ask_place = "novadax"
        except:
            print(coin_list[i] + " not in novadax")

        if is_run == False:
            telegram_send.send(messages=["False novadax"], parse_mode=None)
            break

        #ZT
        symbol_zt = coin_list[i] + "_USDT"
        response_zt = requests.get('https://www.ztb.im/api/v1/tickers')
        zt_dic = json.loads(response_zt.content)
        # print(next(item for item in zt_dic["ticker"] if item["symbol"] == symbol_zt))
        try:
            if "buy" in next(item for item in zt_dic["ticker"] if item["symbol"] == symbol_zt):
                zt_bid_price = float(next(item for item in zt_dic["ticker"] if item["symbol"] == symbol_zt)["buy"])
                print("zt_bid_price "+str(zt_bid_price))
                zt_ask_price = float(next(item for item in zt_dic["ticker"] if item["symbol"] == symbol_zt)['sell'])
                print("zt_ask_price " + str(zt_ask_price))
                if (max_bid_val < zt_bid_price):
                    max_bid_val = zt_bid_price
                    max_bid_place = "zt"
                if (min_ask_val > zt_ask_price):
                    min_ask_val = zt_ask_price
                    min_ask_place = "zt"
        except:
            print(coin_list[i] + " not in zt")

        if is_run == False:
            telegram_send.send(messages=["False zt"], parse_mode=None)
            break
```

my input is something like that:

```
zt_bid_price = 0.12

zt_ask_price = 0.14

novadax_bid_price = 0.13

novadax_ask_price= 0.14
```

To be more clear, I am not getting those results at the same time. I mean it prints in order and I am planning to add more exchanges in the future which means if I decide to print everything at the end of the code that will give me slightly old data. Does anyone have any idea about how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How "old" does this data have to be to be a problem?  If you could do all of the requests concurrently, you'd still have to wait for the slowest one, meaning the fastest ones would now be "old".

Comment: @ScottHunter I haven't thought about it before but so far I am using this program for checking the prices of 60 different coins and it takes more than a minute to check them all. So if I am going to use the same code structure and print the results at the end that will give me pretty outdated results.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation you can use multi-processing to keep each ticker going. However there is overhead for each process which depending on your system, may or may not lag.  You could have all the processes(tickers) running and either on a signal or on a time interval, have each simultaneously poll their source (with time stamp) and return their data.

There is a learning curve.  The line below will get you started.

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
```